# OSGi console commands to list all bundles with unsatisfied constraints?

Tags: osgi

Currently to find problems with my OSGi framework, I use `ss` to list all bundles, see which of them are just `INSTALLED` and not `RESOLVED`, and run `diag <num>` for each number of unresolved bundle. There are problems with this approach:

1. Can't list *only* `INSTALLED` bundles, so I need to find them manually.
2. Some of the bundles won't be resolved because of dependencies on each other, so I get a lot of duplicate information.

What is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

for equinox:

> ss - display installed bundles (short status) 
>   parameters:
>         String[]   [-s ] [segment of bsn]

e.g. ss -s INSTALLED

> ```
> diag - Displays unsatisfied constraints for the specified bundle(s)
>    parameters:
>       long[]   IDs of bundle(s), for which to display unsatisfied constraints
> ```

e.g. diag 1 2 3